# CAS Rest API always causing HTTP Status 415

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, cas

Hi I'm trying to add rest support for my application which uses CAS.

I did all the steps of the tutorials, but when i try from Postman to test the tickets

http://localhost:8080/cas/v1/tickets?username=admin&password=admin

I'm always getting

> HTTP Status 415
>
> The server refused this request because the request entity is in a
>   format not supported by the requested resource for the requested
>   method.

and the response is always as an html page. what is still missing from my side, and what content type should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

I get this too, from a set of new CAS servers I just upgraded from 3.5 to 4.2.5.

The requests succeed if I send them encoded as `x-www-form-urlencoded` using postman (and this is a workaround that I've implemented in our tools that use the REST interface), but not using the `text/plain` content type described in the documentation.  My remaining 3.5 servers accept both content-types.

I'd much rather support both content types, since there are some tools floating around that use the old servers that we don't want to have to update.